# pubsub affiliation set to member is not working in openfire

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, openfire

I have been trying to create a whitelist for my pubsub node on "openfire" and no success yet. Everything goes on very well till the point where I add the members through affiliation request, which setes the affiliation to "member" for specified JIDs. Server accepts the request with no error. But the moment I request the affiliations for the pubsub node, it returns "outcast" instead of "member".
Here are my requests and response:
set affiliation request:

```
<body rid='2568800008' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='6215ff3c'><iq to='pubsub.***.***.2.1' type='set' xmlns='jabber:client' id='1735:sendIQ'><pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner'><affiliations node='hello_pubsub_7'><affiliation jid='arash@***.***.2.1' affiliation='member'/></affiliations></pubsub></iq></body>
```

set affiliation response:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="1735:sendIQ" from="pubsub.***.***.2.1" to="ubuntu@***.***.2.1/6215ff3c"/></body>
```

get affiliation request:

```
<body rid='2568800013' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='6215ff3c'><iq to='pubsub.***.***.2.1' type='get' xmlns='jabber:client' id='1736:sendIQ'><pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner'><affiliations node='hello_pubsub_7'/></pubsub></iq></body>
```

get affiliation response:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="1736:sendIQ" from="pubsub.***.***.2.1" to="ubuntu@***.***.2.1/6215ff3c"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner"><affiliations node="hello_pubsub_7"><affiliation jid="ubuntu@***.***.2.1" affiliation="owner"/><affiliation jid="arash@***.***.2.1" affiliation="outcast"/></affiliations></pubsub></iq></body>
```

It is just "publish-only" and "member" that are not working. "publisher", "owner" and "outcast" are fine.
Not sure if it is a bug or there is something missing in my code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could have saved yourself some debugging by looking at the [docs](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/pubsub/NodeAffiliate.Affiliation.html) first ;)

Only publisher, owner and outcast affiliations are supported.

Comment: You are right, I was so stunned with the xmpp pubsub as a whole and puzzled to find a way to integrate it with another system that I never though about that. Sometimes the answers are way simpler than what you think they are.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither a bug nor something missing in your code.

Openfire's implementation is based on a old version of the spec which does not support that particular affiliation.